# Pantone printing on a roll-up banner?

Tags: color, print-design, print-production, pantone

I heard most of the roll-ups are printed in CMYK. I am wondering if it is possible to print with a Pantone on a Roll-up (canvas)?

Comment: It is likely possible, but it depends both on the artwork and the printing process. If you could show us the design, we would be better equipped to give you an accurate answer

Comment: Thank you. It's basically 3 cmjn images and 2 pms, but they never overlap. The only full-bleed element is the pms. I cannot show you the artwork unfortunately...

Comment: What about if I simply convert the PMS in cmyk in Indesign?

Comment: Just curious but why did you use a Pantone color to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

Digital printers are not built to allow for Pantone colors.  Some digital printers get close if they are offering 6 and 8 color printing but I never seen some guarantee it.  Typically if someone wants a roll-up with Pantone colors we find the CMYK companion from the the [cards](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007X7W3P8).  Another alternative since the cards are very expensive is [this](http://www.lcipaper.com/kb/the-ultimate-color-conversion-chart-pms-cmyk-rgb-hex.html) or [this](http://imjustcreative.com/pantone-color-bridge-cmyk-ec-cheat-sheets/2012/04/19/).  Be advised if you buy the cards (guide) they should only be stored in a dark room or drawer to prevent color fading.

Comment: What about if I simply convert the PMS in cmyk in Indesign?

Comment: you can do that.  I would.  Some charge, but in the end its up to the client and what they are after.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your concept of Pantone.

**1.** Pantone could mean spot color, this is an ink prepared with a specific formula to achieve a specific color to be used directly.

No, an Inkjet printer is normally not prepared to do that.

Of course, you could temper your printer, especially one that can be feed on a tank using different mixtures of ink to shoot a specific color. But probably those base colors will be the basic CMYK ones, so there is no real added value there.

**2.** But if you simply are using Pantone to choose a color, for example assigning that from your vector based application (Illustrator, Corel) This color will be translated using the appropriate ink combination using the printer´s color profile to emulate the color as close as possible.

In some cases, it is a good approach to leave the spot colors as such all the way, so the the color conversion is made by this profile, not before.

Most Pantone colors will be reproducible using this CMYK "simulation" or conversion, but not all colors can.